# delete multiple directories with ansible

Tags: ansible-playbook

Hellos. I need to delete a few directories on a group of machines. I can't seem to get the file module to do my bidding. The below module will run without error and does not delete anything. I do *not* want to remove /opt.

```
- hosts: [dummies]   tasks:
    - name: destroy these paths!
      file: path=/opt{{ item }} state=absent recurse=no
      with_items:
        - "foo"
        - "bar"
        - "baz"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think Ansible is going to add a slash for you.

```
file: path=/opt/{{ item }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For new version of Ansible it does consider / for i am running below for creating the directories:

```
  - name: Creating /dir1 & /dir2
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: directory
    with_items:
     - /dir1
     - /dir2
```

If we have remove directories i think below should work:

```
  - name: Removing dir1 & dir2
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    with_items:
     - dir1
     - dir2
```